# How can I animate a bitmap's opacity using Canvas in Android?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm fairly new to Android programming. I'm trying to create an animation of a bitmap image using `Canvas` in Android. I am using `setAlpha()` to manipulate the opacity of the bitmap. My `drawFrame()` method includes the following bit:

```
c = holder.lockCanvas();  
drawScene(c, paint);  
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

My `drawScene()` includes this bit:

```
Paint transparencyValue = new Paint();  
transparencyValue.setAlpha(paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(boom.getImage(), logoToBoom.getX(), logoToBoom.getY(),
    transparencyValue);
```

I imagine I have to insert a loop to modify `paint` from 0 to 255 and back down. So far it hasn't worked, but I am probably doing something wrong. Could anyone please recommend something?

**EDIT**: Here is my code for the `Runnable`. `paint` is a `private double` set to 255. `boom_activated` is a `boolean` that becomes `true` if the `onTouchEvent` enabled it. It should stay `true` until the `Runnable` disables it (`setBoomState(false);`). For some reason it's still not drawing the bitmap at the decreasing opacity. Is the code below valid, or am I missing something?

```
    private final Runnable DrawSceneThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (boom_activated && paint <= 0) {
                paint = 0;
                drawFrame();
                setBoomState(false);
                paint = 255;
            } else if (boom_activated && paint >= 0) {
                drawFrame();
                paint -= 0.7;
            } else {
                drawFrame();
            }`
```

In my `drawScene()` I have this line:
                `scene_handler.postDelayed(DrawSceneThread, 25);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to animate the opacity values over time. You need to use a handler to update the alpha values and then draw the bitmap in your onDraw function. Have a look at this tutorial to get a better idea about updating the UI through handlers: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Can't post code very well in comments :(
Refer to main post for the edit ^

Comment: You don't need to call drawFrame() yourself. Just invalidate the view and onDraw will be called automatically. Are you overriding onDraw in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this topic
[How to change a bitmap's opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118894/set-alpha-of-bitmap-image)

Also, I would recommend to take your Paint instance and paint variable out of your drawScene and declare it in a global scope so you can reuse it. It would hurt performance when recreating it over and over.

Comment: I am using Canvas. Would the line below properly display the paint as declared in my original post, as opposed to what I use right now?
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);