# porting ios CGContextDrawImage to android

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

I am porting a iOS game to Android using cocos2dx. The idea of the game is to deform a image and convert it into physics shapes in realtime. The logic of the game is to first create a CGContext out of a texture using CGContextDrawImage and then manipulate the context on touch using different blend modes like so:

```
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
  CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, texture);
```

After that the dirty pixels are updated in the texture:

```
  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, w, h, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dirtyPixels);
```

This works fine on iOS but not on Android since it doesn't have core graphics (doh). I am looking for a way to make this code platform independent and since the blending of two images  is really simple my idea was to swap the CGContextDrawImage with my own code to blend pixels in memory.

If i would implement my own code for blending pixels would it be much slower than using core graphics (even if i would optimize the blending in every way possible) or should i find a way and implement the blending for each platform separately (using core graphics on iOS and whatever is available on Android)? Or is there a better way (i have tried offloading blending on the GPU but the sync to get the pixels back is too slow)?

Comment: With the exception of a the very few Intel Atom-based Android phones, you won't be using SSE for this job. Far more likely to be ARM's NEON VPU.  Native code is generally something to avoid, simply on grounds of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you “optimize the blending in every way possible”, you would be at least as fast as Core Graphics. It's not magic; it's just code that you didn't write. It's probably really well-optimized code, though, so you'd have your work cut out for you.

> or should i find a way and implement the blending for each platform separately (using core graphics on iOS and whatever is available on Android)?

That's what I'd do. Let Apple and Google do the hard work for you.

I'm not an Android developer, so I can't really make any specific suggestions or endorsements, but you might try [the code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747119/blending-two-images-together-with-multiply-and-opacity) as a rough outline of what you need to do on Android—or even exactly what you need to do, if you don't need to adjust the second image's opacity.

Comment: just as i suspected. it would probably be a good idea to do a benchmark test to see how much slower would the blending be. if it is only a couple millisecond than i would prefer the cross platform solution since it is less work. thank you.

Comment: did a benchmark and using a custom algorithm and it is 10 times faster than using drawImage (i am using quite small images tho).

Comment: @blejzz: Interesting. 10 times faster on iOS or on Android? Is your code vectorized or GPU-based, or just a straight loop?

Comment: on iOS. its just a straight loop that scales a texture and blends it into a small texture (one is 32x32 and the other 120x180). I think core graphics is backed by gpu and it takes longer to sync the data from gpu to cpu than a simple loop.