# How to dynamically change the opacity of the bitmap in android

Tags: android, opacity, alpha, seekbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set alpha of Bitmap image!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118894/set-alpha-of-bitmap-image)

I want to change the opacity of bitmap on change of seekbar's progress. I am using the below code.

```
opacityseekbar.setMax(255);
opacityseekbar.setProgress(255);
opacityseekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
                {

                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }

                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("Progress Value", "Progress number" + arg1);


                        Bitmap mutableBitmap = theTattoo.isMutable()? theTattoo: theTattoo.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                        int colour = ((opacityseekbar.getProgress() << 24) & 0xFF000000);
                        canvas.drawColor(colour, Mode.DST_IN);

                        theTattoo=mutableBitmap;




                    }
                });
```

But, when I try to do this. It change the opacity very fast as comparison to the seekbar. Also It always decreases the opacity even when when we increase the seek bar. What is wrong I am doing? Please share your suggestions.

Comment: canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue));

Comment: try searching first http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+bitmap+opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Color.argb .. here is sample code.

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue));
```

where alpha is opacity so you can use your progess value in alpha..

here aplha, red, green & blue must be 0 to 255

in your case you have to pass everytime same RGB just change Alpha value

Comment: And we have to set the R, G, B values to? I think @Dalmas answer is a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `BitmapDrawable` instead of working with a `Bitmap` directly.

It's much easier to change the opacity :

```
BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
bmpDrawable.setAlpha(150);
```

Comment: I need to get the final result as bitmap

Comment: In this case you can create a new Bitmap, and draw the BitmapDrawable on the bitmap.

Comment: I tried this code. But it is returning the same bitmap again and again. I think it works only with static change in opacity not dynamic.

Comment: also this is not working only in HTC one M8. not sure why

Comment: To get the final result as a bitmap, simply call `bmpDrawable.getBitmap();`