# Android - ImageView selected state without an additional image?

Tags: android

I want imageview to become brighter when an user presses (clicks) it, but without an additional image for that state. Is it possible?
We know we have selectors where 2 different images can be used, but I would like to have a selector, a drawable from XML, and one real image.

Comment: You mi8 achieve it by altering your alpha value of the image dynamically

Comment: But in Java code, onTouch or on click?

Comment: Thanks. On touch rather - so that I can revert it to the normal state.

Comment: ya, hopefully it helps:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working. Add

```
implements OnTouchListener
```

to the definition of your activity, add

```
.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

to all your imageviews that must respond to click with getting brighter, and add:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View pV, MotionEvent pEvent) {
    if(pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        ((ImageView)pV).setAlpha(128);
    }
    else if(pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        ((ImageView)pV).setAlpha(255);
    }
    return true;
}
```

to your activity. That's all.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with bitmap drawables.  See @dotsamuelswan answer and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118894/set-alpha-of-bitmap-image

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap;
Drawable drawableBitmap= new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
drawableBitmap.SetAlpha(--change here--);
```

convert image to drawable.
set alpha.